# What does = (equal) do in f-strings inside the expression curly brackets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-3.8, f-string

The usage of {} in Python f-strings is well known to execute pieces of code and give the result in `string` format (some tutorials *here*). However, what does the '**=**' at the end of the expression mean?

```
log_file = open("log_aug_19.txt", "w") 
console_error = '...stuff...'           # the real code generates it with regex
log_file.write(f'{console_error=}')
```

Comment: I would recommend to check out this [f-string debugging in Python 3.8](https://tirkarthi.github.io/programming/2019/05/08/f-string-debugging.html) blog.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This is actually a [brand-new feature as of Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging).

> Added an `=` specifier to f-strings. An f-string such as `f'{expr=}'`
>   will expand to the text of the expression, an equal sign, then the
>   representation of the evaluated expression.

Essentially, it facilitates the frequent use-case of print-debugging, so, whereas we would normally have to write:

```
f"some_var={some_var}"
```

we can now write:

```
f"{some_var=}"
```

So, as a demonstration, using a shiny-new Python 3.8.0 REPL:

```
>>> print(f"{foo=}")
foo=42
>>>
```

Comment: Follow-up question: Is there a way to combine this with pretty-printing for dicts and complex structures?

Answer (score 11):

From Python 3.8, f-strings support "self-documenting expressions", mostly for print de-bugging. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html):

> Added an = specifier to f-strings. An f-string such as f'{expr=}' will
>   expand to the text of the expression, an equal sign, then the
>   representation of the evaluated expression. For example:
>
> ```
> user = 'eric_idle'
> member_since = date(1975, 7, 31)
> f'{user=} {member_since=}'
> "user='eric_idle' member_since=datetime.date(1975, 7, 31)"
> ```
>
> The usual f-string format specifiers allow more control over how the
>   result of the expression is displayed:
>
> ```
> >>> delta = date.today() - member_since
> >>> f'{user=!s}  {delta.days=:,d}'
> 'user=eric_idle  delta.days=16,075'
> ```
>
> The = specifier will display the whole expression so that calculations
>   can be shown:
>
> ```
> >>> print(f'{theta=}  {cos(radians(theta))=:.3f}')
> theta=30  cos(radians(theta))=0.866
> ```

Answer (score 9):

This was introduced in python 3.8. It helps reduce a lot of `f'expr = {expr}` while writing codes. You can check the docs at [What's new in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html).

A nice example was shown by [Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger) in his [tweet](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1153085050650423296):

```
>>> from math import radians, sin
>>> for angle in range(360):
        print(f'{angle=}\N{degree sign} {(theta:=radians(angle))=:.3f}')
angle=0° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.000
angle=1° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.017
angle=2° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.035
angle=3° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.052
angle=4° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.070
angle=5° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.087
angle=6° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.105
angle=7° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.122
angle=8° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.140
angle=9° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.157
angle=10° (theta:=radians(angle))=0.175
...
```

You can also check out [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue36817) to get the underlying idea on why this was proposed in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

`f'{a_string=}'` is not exactly the same as `f'a_string={a_string}'`

The former escapes special characters while the latter does not.

e.g:

```
    a_string = 'word 1 tab \t double quote \\" last words'
    print(f'a_string={a_string}')
    print(f'{a_string=}')
```

gets:

```
    a_string=word 1 tab      double quote \" last words
    a_string='word 1 tab \t double quote \\" last words
```

I just realised that the difference is that the latter is printing the repr while the former is just printing the value. So, it would be more accurate to say:

`f'{a_string=}'` is the same as `f'a_string={a_string!r}'`
and allows formatting specifications.

Answer (score 1):

As mention [here](https://pythonprinciples.com/ask/f-strings-what-does-an-equals-sign-do/):

> Equals signs are now allowed inside f-strings starting with Python 3.8. This lets you quickly evaluate an expression while outputting the expression that was evaluated. It's very handy for debugging.:

It mean it will run the execution of the code in the f-string braces, and add the result at the end with the equals sign.

So it virtually means:

```
"something={executed something}"
```