# Print arg name with format strings for debug output

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

It is common to use format strings (or f-strings) to print variables for debugging. However one needs to repeat the argument names if they should be printed as well.

```
[first_name, last_name, age] = ["Randall", "Munroe", 37]
print(f"first_name={first_name} last_name={last_name} age={age}")
```

Is there a shorter way to produce the same (or similar) output of names and values with f-strings?

I believe I have seen a short form however I did not find any mention in the [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-string debugging shorthand in Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296925/f-string-debugging-shorthand-in-python-3-6)

Comment: Or better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661904/what-does-equal-do-in-f-strings-inside-the-expression-curly-brackets

Comment: @mkrieger1 The linked question answers my question well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter form (aka "shorthand") is to write `{a=}`instead of `a={a}`.

```
[first_name, last_name, age] = ["Randall", "Munroe", 37]
print(f"{first_name=} {last_name=} {age=}")
```