# What causes the difference between `f"{a}"` vs `f"{a=}"` in python's f strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

In the following python code, what causes the difference in outputs?

```
try:
    open('nonexistent')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'{err=}')
    print(f'{err}')
```

result:

```
err=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nonexistent'
```

In this instance, the second is more useful, but I'm surprised there's a difference at all. What's the cause of this, and what's the logic behind this design decision?

I'm using Python 3.8.3.

Comment: Your code is very different from your title. Your title says `f"a={a}"`. Your code just says `f'{err}'`, not `f'err={err}'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does = (equal) do in f-strings inside the expression curly brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661904/what-does-equal-do-in-f-strings-inside-the-expression-curly-brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the f-string [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

> When the equal sign '=' is provided, the output will have the expression text, the '=' and the evaluated value. Spaces after the opening brace '{', within the expression and after the '=' are all retained in the output. By default, the '=' causes the repr() of the expression to be provided, unless there is a format specified. When a format is specified it defaults to the str() of the expression unless a conversion '!r' is declared.

Since you did not specify a format, `f'{err=}'` applies `repr` instead of `str` to `err`. This is a more useful default than `str` for the debugging use cases the `=` f-string syntax was designed for.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `f{err}` gives `str(err)` (explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)) and hence the difference noted by OP