# Example program of acados not running

Tags: python, installation

## Problem

---

I want test my installation of acados. However i run into a problem when running the first example to test my installation:

Running the recommended example:

```bash
$ python minimal_example_ocp.py
```

I get the following:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal_example_ocp.py", line 31, in <module>
    from acados_template import AcadosOcp, AcadosOcpSolver
  File "/home/papaveneti/acados/interfaces/acados_template/acados_template/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .acados_ocp import AcadosOcp, AcadosOcpConstraints, AcadosOcpCost, AcadosOcpDims, AcadosOcpOptions
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (self.cost.cost_type_0=)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I appreciate any insight into the problem and how to fix it.

## Steps i followed in the installation:

---

1. I followed the steps for installation in linux with cmake, that are listed [here](https://docs.acados.org/installation/#linux-mac). **Built was successful with no errors**
2. Then, i wanted to build the [python interface](https://docs.acados.org/python_interface/index.html#installation).

So first. i downloaded python 3.7 as per [these](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-linux/#Method-1-Install-Python-37-on-Ubuntu-2204-or-2004-via-LaunchPAD-PPA) instructions. That is:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.7
sudo apt install python3.7-full
```

and then i created a virtuan environment and instaled the `acados_template` package:

```bash
cd acados
python3.7 -m venv vEnv
source vEnv/bin/activate
pip install -e ~/acados/interfaces/acados_template
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"$HOME/acados/lib"
export ACADOS_SOURCE_DIR="$HOME/acados"
```

3. And then i try to run the example:

```bash
cd ~/acados/examples/acados_python/getting_started
python3.7 minimal_example_ocp.py # or even python minimal_example_ocp.py
```

## Extra checks and info

With `pip list -l` i get the `acados_template` package:

```
acados-template   0.2.6   /home/<user>/acados/interfaces/acados_template
```

and `python --version` gives me python 3.7.17.

I have ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Line 32 from `/home/papaveneti/acados/interfaces/acados_template/acados_template/__init__.py`
is the following:

```py
from .acados_ocp import AcadosOcp, AcadosOcpConstraints, AcadosOcpCost, AcadosOcpDims, AcadosOcpOptions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Python is too old for the [`{foo=}` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59661904/51685) in that file. (That said, are you sure that's the full traceback? It looks like there may be some lines missing.)

The `=` syntax for f-strings was added in Python 3.8. It's unfortunate that the documentation suggests using Python 3.7 if it doesn't work.

You should upgrade to a [supported version](https://endoflife.date/python) of Python 3.

Comment: i just created a virtual environment with **python3.8.10** which came by default on ubuntu and the example worked. Thanks for the answer.